# How do I select the second part of a class in CSS?

Tags: css

I would like to select the `hour-hand`, `min-hand` and `second-hand` parts of the 'hand' class. I am trying to enter in `.hand hour-hand` into CSS but it doesn't select it.

Essentially I want to make the `second-hand` red instead of black, but right now the only class in CSS is the following:

```css
.hand {
  width: 50%;
  height: 6px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform-origin: 100%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: all 0.05s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="clock">
  <div class="clock-face">
    <div class="hand hour-hand"></div>
    <div class="hand min-hand"></div>
    <div class="hand second-hand"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can I create a separate class for the second hand in this case?

Comment: `.hand.hour-hand` (with no space), but `.hour-hand` or `.second-hand` should be sufficient so long as the definition is placed _after_ that of `.hand`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you only need `.second-hand` to do so.
You can have many classes on one element.
In this case, `.hand` is the base for all, and the other classes become modifiers.

`.hand.second-hand` would also work but is unnecessary in this case.